# Google Optimize not initializing with react-helmet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-helmet, google-optimize

When adding **Google Optimize** into your webpage, you would normally add this script tag into your header like this

```
<head>
   <script src="https://www.googleoptimize.com/optimize.js?id=OPT-ABC123">
   </script>
</head>
```

I am running a React.js app with node.js Server-Side-Rendering (SSR) and I initially used React-Helmet to inject this script tag into my  element like this:

```
<Helmet>
   <script src="https://www.googleoptimize.com/optimize.js?id=OPT-ABC123">
   </script>
</Helmet>
```

Running this in SSR mode, outputs the expected  tag, the browser loads the script, but it fails to initialise Google Optimize correctly (because the 'Google Tag Legacy Assistant` chrome extension tells me).

We use react-helmet in many other places on out website and it works perfectly fine, but not for Optimize.

I tried adding the script into our static index.html file directly - without react-helmet - and it works **perfectly**.

```
<head>
   <script src="https://www.googleoptimize.com/optimize.js?id=OPT-ABC123">
   </script>
</head>
```

I noticed that when react-helmet renders the  tag it also injects a `data-react-helmet="true"` attribute, which I understand it uses internally to prevent duplicate  tags being injected.

I tried adding that attribute into my static index.html file and notice that **Optimize no longer loaded**.

```
<head>
   <script data-react-helmet="true" src="https://www.googleoptimize.com/optimize.js?id=OPT-ABC123">
   </script>
</head>
```

I can't understand why the extra attribute would prevent this otherwise pure  tag to work as expected. I assume either the browser doesn't like the `data-*` attribute or react-helmet is doing something funky with the hardcoded  tag.

Thoughts:

- I wonder if the server-side-render is messing with anything, especially when react.js does the client-side "hydration" step, which might it to re-render the  tag somehow...?

Help! :)

**UPDATE #1**
<s>Adding timestamp to the script URL's querystring, didn't work in the end. It must have been cached somehow</s>:(

Comment: Is that the actual script URL?

Comment: I've used a random ID in the querystring, so it may not return the actual optimize script.

Comment: uBlock Origin is also blocking the googleoptimize.com domain for me, could this be part of it?

Comment: What is uBlock origin? Does that run in chrome by default?

Comment: It's a very popular Adblocker extension and I thought maybe you had that running. Not by default, no.

Comment: Ah! My Update #1 (timestamp in querystring) stopped working shortly after, so ignore that